# Please Help me Understand how to detect errors in my program from logcat

Tags: android, logcat

My app has stopped working on the emulator"Unfortunately". I have the logcat with me, however I dont understand how to solve the errors. Please help me. Thanks in advance. Here's the logcat

```
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.calc/my.calc.CalcActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at my.calc.CalcActivity.onCreate(CalcActivity.java:30)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

the above line indicates you have null pointer exception and the below indicated the line number(CalcActivity.java:30).

```
05-07 14:34:01.302: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at my.calc.CalcActivity.onCreate(CalcActivity.java:30)
```

and hopefully you may had forget to use setContentView in oncreate() and using xml file components.

**Updated:::**

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(CalcActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, your_array_list_of_charsequence);
```

try by adding above line before     `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Comment: Sorry, this is turning into a rolling debug session, and I'm shutting that down now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain what all those "at"s mean... It's called a stack trace and is a way for you to determine what your application was doing when something went wrong. Imagine you have the following PseudoCode

File1:

```
1 define function MyFunction(SomeParam)
2     Throw an exception here
3 end definition
```

File2:

```
1 DoSomething()
2 DoSomethingElse()
3 Call MyFunction
4 DoSomething()
```

What you would see in the stack trace is something like

```
Exception Thrown
at File1 Line 2
at File2 Line 3
```

This is telling you that the exception is thrown in your `MyFunction` in `File1` when it is being called from `File2`.

Obviously, in a real program, lots of functions call lots of other functions so stack traces can be quite a bit longer - but the principle is the same.

One other thing to be aware of when using frameworks is that it's possible for the exception to be thrown in code you haven't written yourself. This either means you're using the framework wrong or the framework has a bug. 99% of the time it's because you're using it wrong

If it's a framework exception, follow back up the stack trace until you find the bit of code you've written which is calling the framework. This is most likely where the problem is.

Hope that helps clarify what you're seeing